# Поменять расположение символов в строке

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть у меня `value` в которой содержится строка наподобие `&#x440;&#x443;&#x431;.260000` (обязательно присутствуют символы & или #) Мне нужно поменять элементы передвинуть число 260000 вперед, а закодированную кирилицу `&#x440;&#x443;&#x431;.` назад - вот так: `260000&#x440;&#x443;&#x431;.`

```
if(value.contains("&#")) {
var out = value.replace(/^([^\d]*)([\d]*)/g,'$2 $1');
console.log(out); }
```

вот так получаю ошибку - `value.contains is not a function`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Тут есть 2 проблемы:

1. В JavaScript нет метода `String.prototype.contains`.
2. Регулярное выражение в вашем примере кода *не будет работать* так, как вы того ожидаете.

Таким образом, правильный код выглядит как-то так:

```
if(value.toString().indexOf("&#") !== -1) {
    var out = value.replace(/^(.*?)([\d]*)$/, '$2$1');
    console.log(out);
}
```

**UPD:**

Если нужно каким-то образом изменить части строки перед перестановкой, можно использовать следующий подход:

```
if(value.toString().indexOf("&#") !== -1) {
    var out = value.replace(/^(.*?)([\d]*)$/, function(match, p1, p2) {
        // p1 и p2 группы, захваченные регулярным выражением.
        // Если value = '&#x440;&#x443;&#x431;.260000', то:
        //   p1 = '&#x440;&#x443;&#x431;.'
        //   p2 = '260000'
        // Для примера, склеим эти строки вместе в обратном порядке.
        return p2 + p1;
    });
}
```

Comment: проблема оказывается еще в другом: значение `value` скрипт воспринимает не как строку, а как значение, поэтому на `indexOf` он ругается `value.indexOf is not a function`

Comment: Для приведения к строке можно использовать метод `.toString()`. Отредактировал ответ.

Comment: да, спасибо, помогло. остался последний вопрос: после всех преобразований ответ выводит в таком виде: `260000руб.`, а хотелось бы, чтобы был пробел после числа и точкой разделялись тысячи, миллионы, т.е. `260.000 руб.`

Comment: Обновил ответ, показав, как можно работать с захваченными подстроками. А вообще, форматирование числа (отделение тысяч) выходит за рамки первоначального вопроса. Пример того, как это сделать можете посмотреть вот здесь: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-money-in-javascript . А можете  использовать готовую библиотеку (например http://numeraljs.com/).

Comment: спасибо. окончательное решение было вот такое:
`value.replace(/^(.*?)(\d+)$/g,'$2 $1').replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+([^\d]|$))/g, '$1.');`

Answer (score 3):

В JavaScript у строки нет такого метода. Используйте indexOf для поиска есть ли такое вхождение подстроки.

Если очень сильно хочется, то можно самому ее определить:

```
String.prototype.contains = function(it) { return this.indexOf(it) != -1; };
```

Comment: первая часть получилось - теперь загвоздка переставить элементы. у меня regplace работает на цифры, а нужно на зашифрованные символы `&#x443;`